# Image X & Y axe

Tags: javascript, image, dictionary, scripting, sa-mp

i have a image (1536x1536), it's a map.

And i want to have X and Y axe on image max x: 3000.0, max y: 3000.0, min x: -3000.0, min y: -3000.0.

I want to to convert my coordinates (X,Y) in position on map (top/bottom and left/right)

Comment: So you blow the image up by styling to 6000px x 6000px or higher? Or do you want to calculate closest point in scale 6000 to 1536? Is it an `<img>`, `<canvas>` `<svg:` ... ? Do you use `usemap`, or is it by cursor event move, or is it not pointer related at all?

Comment: It's img, i want to do a Live Map, and i want to convert coordinates of game on image.

Comment: I have this script:

  var size = document.getElementById('unique_map'); 
  var xMod = 6000/size.width;
  var yMod = 6000/size.height;
  var xPoint = x / xMod;
  var yPoint = y / yMod;
  xPoint = xPoint + (size.width / 2);
  yPoint = -(yPoint - (size.height / 2));
  var source = "#circle_id_" + ID;
  $(source).css("left", xPoint);
  $(source).css("top", yPoint);
  
Work but not exactly.

Comment: Did you find it helpful? Also note that you have to take into account offset, margins etc of image, wrappers, HTML body etc. when positioning the elements. But guess you are aware of this ...

Answer (score 0):

From comments I assume you do not resize image by CSS but keep it in it's natural state. As such you can use a translate object with ratio difference. If this is *extremely* resource dependent I recommend using array over object (as to code displayed below).

It give you point to pixel translation.

```
var translate = {
    x: 1536 / 6000,
    y: 1536 / 6000
};

function pt_translate(pt) {
    return {
        x: Math.round((pt.x + 3000) * translate.x),
        y: Math.round((pt.y + 3000) * translate.y)
    };
}

// Sample coordinate input:
pt = {
    x: -1029.3652,
    y:  369.122
};

var ptt = pt_translate(pt);
```

Result:

```
{x: 504, y: 862}
```

More samples:

<kbd>***[Various console log samples](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/337Hk/)***</kbd>

```
console.log(pt_translate({x:0,y:0}), 'vs', 1536 / 2, 1536 / 2);
console.log(pt_translate({x:3000,y:3000}), 'vs', 1536, 1536);
console.log(pt_translate({x:-3000,y:-3000}), 'vs', 0,0);
console.log(pt_translate({x:910,y:-1045}), 'vs', 1000,500);
console.log(ptt);
```

Yields:

```
{x: 768, y: 768} "vs" 768 768
{x: 1536, y: 1536} "vs" 1536 1536
{x: 0, y: 0} "vs" 0 0
{x: 1000, y: 500} "vs" 1000 500
{x: 504, y: 862}
```